# Calculating covariance between 2 planes with NumPy

Tags: python, image, image-processing, numpy

Suppose we have two frames of a video and we want to return a matrix of the covariance between the two frames. This matrix will have the same dimensions as one of the two frames.

I've simplified my code below. This is part of a class implementation, so much of it wasn't necessary to show.

```
def covar(self,frame):

    return np.cov(current_frame,next_frame)
```

This returns a plane as  I wanted. But the problem with the above is that it returns much larger dimensions. It would help to know how the np.cov returns a value. Any pointers?

**Edit**:

I'd like to clarify what I meant. My 2 frames are grayscale images represented by intensity values in a matrix. Each value maps to a pixel. I am trying to find the covariance between a pixel in one frame and the next frame.

(Also, I prefer to use NumPy or other very efficient computational methods as there may be thousands of images in my stack.)

**Edit2**:

Suppose I'd like to use OpenCV since NumPy isn't great for image processing. Any tips on using the calcCovarMatrix function (http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html)?

Comment: What do you mean by "covariance of two matrices"? Covariance of a set of images would have D^2 dimension, where D=number of elements of an array, so if you have 2 10x10 arrays the resulting covariance matrix is 100x100

Comment: Read the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cov.html) and click on the link "source" on that page to know how it worls.

Comment: Here's what I meant. My 2 frames are grayscale images represented by intensity values in a matrix. Each value maps to a pixel. I am trying to find the covariance between a pixel in one frame and the next frame. I'll add this to the above question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It would help to know how the np.cov returns a value. Any pointers?

Yes. [Official Documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cov.html#numpy.cov)

I think you want to look at statistical properties of one specific pixel position. To do that, think of the frame as just one observation of a set of pixels; the next frame is the next observation of the same set.

This results in an approach not unlike

```
import numpy
a = numpy.ravel(frame1)
b = numpy.ravel(frame2)
c = numpy.column_stack((a,b))
res = numpy.cov(c)
```

`res` will then have a dimension of `(rows*cols, rows*cols)`, like you would expect from a covariance matrix.

Comment: Hmm, yeah I've seen the documentation. Just not understanding it. If I have 2 matrices (of equal dimension) and I stack them on top of each other, how can I find the covariance between each pixel on top and bottom (and then plot that covariance in respective locations on a new matrix)? I might not be wording my question correctly, please let me know if that is the case.

Comment: You might be misunderstanding covariance between vectors/matrices.

Comment: See finished comment^

Comment: Just trying to find out if there is an efficient way to calculate the covariance between two pixels from corresponding locations on two images, and put the result in a matrix of equal dimension.

Comment: um, ok. So covariance tells you how much the changingness of one value relates to the changingness of all other values in your observation; one "observation" here is one frame. Thus, you get one frame worth of covariance values for each pixel in your images -- I really don't think this is what you want, anymore. Are you maybe trying to find a per-pixel autocorrelation coefficient?

Comment: Yes, I think I may have gotten autocovariance confused with covariance. Any suggestions on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the following. I often compute correlation between two successive frames, e.g. I use this for determining a depth, where the correlation is 0.5, which means we have a SNR equal to 0 (the penetration depth).

I do the following:

```
# Window used for averaging
winrows = 3
wincols = 21

eps = np.finfo(np.float64).eps

win = np.ones((winrows, wincols)) / winrows / wincols

# I have my own conv2 (like Matlab), so use convolve2d from scipy.signal instead
R11 = rfdata1 * rfdata1.conjugate()
R11 = np.sqrt(np.abs(conv2(R11, win, 'same')))
R11[R11 == 0] = eps

R22 = rfdata2 * rfdata2.conjugate()
R22 = np.sqrt(np.abs(conv2(R22, win, 'same')))
R22[R22 == 0] = eps

R12 = rfdata1 * rfdata2.conjugate()
R12 = np.abs(conv2(R12, win, 'same'))
R12 = R12 / R11 / R22

R12[R12 > 1] = 1
```

The matrix R12 now contains the absolute correlation coefficients (truncated to the range [-1,1]). You can also use convolve from scipy.ndimage.filters, it is very fast, but it is offset by 1 compared to Matlab's conv2.

To make this computational effective, conv2 can be defined like this

```
from scipy.ndimage.filters import convolve

def conv2(x,y,mode='same'):
    """
    Emulate the function conv2 from Mathworks.

    Usage:

    z = conv2(x,y,mode='same')

    """

    if not(mode == 'same'):
        raise Exception("Only same is supported")

    if not(len(x.shape) == len(y.shape)):
        raise Exception("Number of dimensions must match")

    origin = ()

    # Apparently, the origin must be set in a special way to reproduce
    # the results of scipy.signal.convolve
    for i in range(len(x.shape)):
        if (x.shape[i] - y.shape[i]) % 2 == 0:
            origin = origin + (-1,)
        else:
            origin = origin + (0,)

    if (mode == 'same'):
        z = convolve(x,y, mode='constant', origin=origin)

    return z
```

Comment: Most likely, you will need some sort of average for the correlations of regions in your image. It is very unlikely that you can use numpy.cov for image analysis.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this out. I made a comment in edit2 about OpenCV.

Comment: I use OpenCV for similar stuff too. The scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve is just as fast

Comment: Hi Jens, I sort of understand what you mean now. But I guess I just worded my question poorly. I have boiled down my data to two image stacks. I want to calculate the covariance at each point between the two image stacks and return a matrix with the covariance as points. 

How could I use the convolve function to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I wanted to do.

Previously, I had calculated the variance off all pixels (at a point) across a stack of images and plotted that as a matrix. It took me a while, but I realized that the covariance (which I wanted all along) between the intensities of the pixels was equal to twice the variance!

My return statement is this, and it appears to work. If there's a reason this works, please let me know.

```
    return 2*np.var(stack,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Take two images, img1 and img2, and define following python function

```
def Covariance(x, y):
    xbar, ybar = x.mean(), y.mean()
    return np.sum((x - xbar)*(y - ybar))/(len(x) - 1)
```

Now call the function,as following way

```
print("Covariance(img1,img2)  :", Covariance(img1,img2))
```

it will give you the appropriate Covariance between two images.